# Matching div id with with option select

Tags: jquery

Trying to match an option select with a div id containing the same name. My only problem is that I am unsure how to attribute the name of the selection into jQuery. The last line is where I am stuck.

```
$('#carlist').change(function(){
var chosen = $(this).val();
$('.cars').hide();
$('.cars').attr(''+chosen+'').fadeIn();
});
```

JS Fiddle below.
https://jsfiddle.net/Lc4w2v3r/

I want to match the div id (for example, Jetta), with the option select of the exact same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the target div (for example) with `$('#Saab')` and since you already got the variable `chosen` you can do something like this:

```
$('#carlist').change(function(){
    var chosen = $(this).val();
    $('.cars').hide();
    $('#' + chosen).fadeIn();
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc4w2v3r/3/)

Comment: "<option>Volvo</option>" for the 3rd option instead of Ford but yes, this is correct.

Comment: I just kept the values from his Fiddle, but yes, the 3rd one doesn't have a matching div.